# Why my view model data is not referring to the values i have already changed in android kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to set a value from the main activity in the viewmodel by calling a method but it doesn't change the value when I am trying to reference it inside the view model.
This is what i have done. I have a variable called name in the view model and I have a setName method which accepts a name and set it in the viewmodel

```
class MainViewModel {
.
.
.
  private var name: String = "DEFAULT"

  fun setName(name: String) {
     this.name = name
  }

  fun printName(){
    println("NAME " + this.name) // DEFAULT
  }

  fun getName(): String {
   return this.name
 }


}
```

setName function is called from the main activity as follows,

```
class MainActivity: AppCompatActivity() {
.
.
.

 private val viewModel by viewModel<MainViewModel>();

 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    var button: Button = findViewById(R.id.button)
    button.setOnClickListener {
         this.viewModel.setName("TEST NAME")
         println("NAME " + this.viewModel.getName()) // TEST NAME
    }
  }

}
```

But inside the printName function when I try to access the variable within the viewModel it's still DEFAULT. How can i make sure that the viewModel name variable is synchronized in the mainactivity and in the viewmodal. What i want to simply achieve is the value "TEST NAME" should be reflected on the name variable irrespective from where i access it

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the part of code where you call `printName`

Comment: Writing getter and setter functions for a property is an antipattern in Kotlin. You're creating redundant getters and setters because properties already have them, and they subvert expected syntax. And yes, we need to see where you call `printName` to be able to tell what might be going wrong. Also, you should Log instead of using `println` on Android.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Thanks a lot guys got what I was doing wrong I am referring to two seperate instances when trying to get() inside the DI

Comment: @SergeiKozelko thanks a lot was able to resolve this